# Does sim800l has an url limit?

Tags: arduino, at-command, sim800l

I want to send an information to web server with arduino via sim800l.

```
 AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://api.trackers.live/v3.0.0/TRCKR02B2AF359D19/40.35715122342342322432-36.077406243242342-1469134234/1212/021/16553"
```

When I want to send long url to web server,the program crashes.
Does sim800l has an url limit? or is there any possible way to send an url like this?

Comment: What does the datasheet for the part say?  Also your code is off-topic for `arduino`, as it contains no code. A URL is not code.  And the very first search hit I found is a complete tutorial on how to use this part.  Do your research.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all modems have a limit in how many characters they accept on a command line. [The V.250 specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) says in chapter "5.2.1 Command line general format":

> A command line is made up of three elements: the prefix, the body, and the termination character. ... The DCE shall be capable of accepting at least 40 characters in the body.

The prefix is the two characters "AT" or "at" and the termination character should be '\r', thus a modem (aka DCE, Data Circuit-terminating Equipment) is allowed to only accept as low as 43 characters on a command line.

Now the was majority of modem supports more, probably that 40 character limit was due to some old Hayes modem made in the 1970s. If sim800l has decent documentation it should say how many characters it support on a command line. If it has crappy documentation it will not say.

As always with AT command syntax question, the very first source to query should **always** be the manufacturer specific documentation for that particular modem. Failing that you can fall back to V.250 or [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) or [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the limit but you can use a link shortener to shorten the link...